# Give some clarity on this linked-list implementation

Tags: java, linked-list

I tried implementing a singly linked list in java, using the following code. I wrote the code such that the user enters as many digits as he wants and finally when he taps enter key on the keyboard program displays all the digits he entered.

For example, if a user enters something like 12345548963256987451236589745 and then an enter should produce this result "12345548963256987451236589745".

I know I can do this simply using a String or BigInteger but I just wanted to try this with a linked list.

```
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
    Node start=null,end=null;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    char ch ;
    ch = in.next();
    while(ch.charAt(0)!='\n')
    {
        Node n = insert(ch-48);
        if(start==null)
        {
            start = n;
            end = n;
        }
        else
        {
            end.next=n;
            end = n;
        }
        ch  = in.next();
    }
    Node n = start;
    while(n!=null)
    {
        System.out.print(n.data);
        n=n.next;
    }
}
    private static Node insert(int i) {

      Node n = new Node();
      n.data=i;
      n.next = null;
      return n;
     }
```

For some reason, the program is going to an infinite loop. I mean it's never coming out of taking the input part.

I think I messed up something with this line:
                    ch.charAt(0)!='\n'

So what should I change?

I initially tried this in C language and tried to mimic the same in JAVA, it worked in C but it's giving trouble in JAVA.

Comment: What `in.next()` returns to you is the *whole* string of digits, not including the `\n`. So your logic fails. It's also impossible that this compiles if `ch` is defined as `char` rather than `String`.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I tried making ch a string and the condition check in while as while(!ch.equals("end")) and it worked out. But I want to know if it's possible to do this using character

Comment: Given that `Scanner` does *not* return the next character, just the next token, then you shouldn't use a `Scanner`. `Scanner` is intended to tokenize input into strings and numbers. If you want to read characters, use a `Reader`.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to go char by char you can do something like below.

Note that in.next() will consume just characters ignoring '/n', so you should use in.nextLine() then in case of the blank line ('/n' pressed) line length is zero.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String line = in.nextLine();
        int iter = 0;
        while (iter < line.length()) {

            // Node logic

            iter++;
            if(iter == line.length()){
                iter = 0;
                line = in.nextLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't want to form a String in the first place, I want to form the list using only character ch. I tried changing in.next() to in.nextLine() but that didn't work either

Comment: It will not work as you want.
next() - Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner

So always for the given input: 12345548963256987451236589745
You will receive a full string.

Answer (score 0):

In this example it is not necessary to use a `Scanner`. You can just read bytes directly from `System.in` (using the `InputStream::read()` method) and stop as soon as you get a non-digit character.

```
package misc;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Node {
    private int data;
    private Node next;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Node start = null, end = null;
        int ch;
        while(Character.isDigit(ch = System.in.read())) { // or: while((ch = System.in.read()) != '\r') {
            Node n = insert(ch - 48);
            if (start == null) {
                start = n;
                end = n;
            } else {
                end.next = n;
                end = n;
            }
        }

        Node n = start;
        while (n != null) {
            System.out.print(n.data);
            n = n.next;
        }
    }

    private static Node insert(int i) {
        Node n = new Node();
        n.data = i;
        n.next = null;
        return n;
    }
}
```

Example input:
"12345"

Example output:
12345